# Getting habitat map data into CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am fairly new to QGIS and I am doing a masters degree.

I have a number of GPS coordinates which represent the location of elephant sightings.  I need to find out what habitat type each of these coordinates was recorded in (e.g. scrubland, grassland, forest).
To do this I have been trying to use the World Terrestrial Ecosystems map from Esri Landscape (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d9434e94c817434c8448445501aee60a) which is a world map showing many different habitat types.

I have loaded the map into QGIS alongside my GPS coordinates (which can be seen in the attached screenshot)

[image: Habitat map with GPS coordinates overlain]

but i am unsure about how to assign each of these coordinates a habitat type based on the underlying map. I have tried using a point sampling tool which i have used for previous analysis but it just produces a blank csv file with no results.

How could I tackle this?

Comment: More information please on what you're trying to do. Screenshots would help. So would a sample of your data and a link to the World Terrestrial Ecosystems map.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Use QGIS expressions with the function `raster_value()`. Be aware: both layers have to be in the same CRS:

```
 raster_value( 'raster', 1, $geometry)
```

- `raster` is the name of your raster layer.
- `1` is the number of the band.

Comment: Adding to @Babel's amswer, for instance you could edit your point (observations) layer's settings and add a virtual field (Field calculator in the Fields tab) with the expression he provides. This virtual field would then tell you the veg type at each observation point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and the results it produced were blank. I’ve had this issue with all the things I’ve tried and think maybe something is wrong with the map itself?

Comment: Whatbkind of data you have, hiw are your layers saved? Do you have them saved as local files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the processing tool [Sample raster values](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling):

"Extracts raster values at the point locations. "

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and the results it produced were blank. I’ve had this issue with all the things I’ve tried and think maybe something is wrong with the map itself?

Comment: The problem is probably that the layer is a service. You need to download the raster if it is available.