# Buffering with consideration of both distance and height using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer, spatial-analysis, z-value

I have a shapefile with points including their altitude (Z) and a DEM raster.

Basically, what I want is to create various buffers around the points extending up to 50 meters from them, but at the same time, having these buffers limit themselves up to 5 meters above the altitude where the points are ubicated.

So if the altitude doesn't vary past those 5 meters the buffer will reach the 50 meters distance, but if the 5 meters altitude threshold is surpassed the buffer will stop right there even if it hasn't covered the 50 meters distance.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution: basic idea

Create a grid within 50 m from every point and check for each cell if its elevation is within the range of +/- 5 m from the elevation of the point.

#### Step-by-step guide on how to implement it

1. Create 50 m buffers. Name the layer `buffer`.
2. For each buffer, get the elevation of the point they are created from. Use Field calculator and create a new field `elevation_point` with this expression: `raster_value('dem',1, overlay_contains('point',$geometry)[0])`, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431272/88814
3. Create a square grid with the same CRS, extent, and cell size as the DEM raster.
4. Only keep grid cells that intersect with the buffers. Use e.g. ["Select by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) with the geometric predicate `disjoint` and delete selected cells.
5. For each grid cell, get the elevation from the DEM and create a new attribute named `elevation_cell` with the Field Calculator. Use this expression: `raster_value ('dem', 1, centroid ($geometry))`
6. For each grid cell, get the elevation of the buffer/initial point it intersects with. Create a new attribute field called `elev_from_buff` with this expression: `overlay_intersects('buffer',elevation_point)[0]`
7. Select those grid cells that are out of the range of +/- 5+ m from the initial point. Use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) with this expression: `abs (elev_from_buff-elevation_cell) > 5`. Delete the selected cells.

The remaining cells represent the solution you're looking for. To get one continuous feature per initial point (one buffer), select all cells, merge them and run Multipart to Single parts. You're done.